# C++ memory layout of derived classes

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create C++ container class which would satisfy the following constraints:

1. Number of entries is variable, but statically known.
2. Size of each specific object must be also known statically, without any dynamic memory allocation.
3. You should be able to write non-templated function that will enumerate all elements in the container.
4. No virtual methods (it's trivial to do it with them, i'm trying to avoid vtable overhead).
5. Single memory pointer should be sufficient to operate on the container.  It's also trivial to do that with `std::span` and `std::array`, but `std::span` forces you to store length alongside the pointer, which is redundant.

Currently I have the following construction:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>

struct Foo { int x; }

struct Base {
public:
  size_t size() const { return m_size; };
  const Foo *data() const { return m_fooBase; };

protected:
  size_t m_size;
  Foo    m_fooBase[0];

  constexpr explicit Base(size_t sz): m_size(sz) {}
}

template <size_t N>
struct Derived final: public Base {
public:
  Derived(/* ... */): Base(N) {
    /* fill foos */
  }

private:
  std::array<Foo, N> m_foos;
}

static const Derived<3> derived3 = /* ... */;
static const Derived<5> derived5 = /* ... */;

void doSomething(const Base &base) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < base.size(); i++) {
    printf("%d\n", base.data()[i].x);
  }
}

void test() {
  doSomething(derived3);
  doSomething(derived5);
}
```

As I understand, there is no standard guarantee that `foos` would be placed at same address as `fooBase`, even if it is the first member of `Derived`. Static assertion with `offsetof` is also not an option, because `offsetof` is undefined for such classes.

Is there any way to make such container standard-compliant without introducing virtual methods, or at least to formulate proper static assertion?

Comment: [Flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) is not C++.

Comment: Ok, that makes the situation even worse then. Not only layout is undefined, but also it seems like it is GCC extension (since it compiles on GCC). But the overal question is whether it is possible to make such container in a standard-compliant way.

Comment: It's not possible to write `doSomething` function without Base class.

Comment: Isn't `std::array` (possibly with `std::span`) does the job?

Comment: `using Base = std::span<Foo>; template <std::size_t N> using Derived = std::array<Foo, N>;`?

Comment: Just skimming through the question, it sounds like it's describing [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). What does the question need that isn't in `std::array`?

Comment: "Container objects should be able to be operated via pointers without knowing their static size" This doesn't parse.

Comment: Clarified why I'm trying to avoid direct usage of `std::array`. You cannot write non-templated function that will operate on arbitrary sized arrays, and std::span holds two fields - pointer and size.

Comment: @Maxim: "*but std::span forces you to store length alongside the pointer, which is redundant.*" Not if the length is statically known.

Comment: @Maxim: "*You cannot write non-templated function that will operate on arbitrary sized arrays, and std::span holds two fields - pointer and size.*" This is incoherent. `array` has the size as part of the type and is therefore statically known. But the receiving code needs to know the size. Therefore, it is either part of the type or a *member* of the object. Unless your container has some built in terminator value, the size of the array *cannot* be implicit. It is either part of the type or a member of the object. Also, your `Base` has `m_size`, which is what you don't like about `span`.

Comment: @Maxim: This design is functionally equivalent to deriving `array` from `span`. Which is... extremely pointless. Is your concern really just that the size in the `span` will be copied a bunch, such that you want to pass pointers/references to the `span` instead of copying the `span` itself?

Comment: @NicolBolas `Not if the length is statically known.` and the length *isn't* statically known in a non template function that accepts the span.

Comment: @eerorika: But `span<T, N>` can handle that, as it can degrade into a `span<T, dynamic_extent>` where the size gets stored internally. If the function isn't a template, then it *must* use a runtime-provided size, and that size has to live *somewhere*.

Comment: Yes, and it's better for size to live inside of actual structure. This is the whole purpose of `Base` existence - to put size into fixed position before actual data, so you could use just a pointer.

Just for a context - code will run inside of embedded system with very tight code size constraints. This is why I trying to squeeze every byte from it. I would'nt do all that trickery on my PC - vectors are good there.